# How to send multiple string arrays in Socket programming

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I am developing a client/server achitecture, where the server is going to parse news feeds and is going to send it to client (android).

On the client side, I want to display the headlines (as hyperlinked). So I would need to send both the headlines and the associated links from the server to client.

I am new to socket programming. Could anyone please tell me how to send muliple string arrays(2 in my case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried already??

Comment: JSON? XML? Anything you want, really.

Comment: Sorry for posting such silly question. I got it working. Passed the two arrays as Json key value pair. Thanks